# WPF Application - Reducing DWrite.dll/igdumdim64.dll CPU usage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I profiled my WPF application from two versions. The Views and ViewModels got tweeked a lot and I replaced a lot of code. Somehow the CPU usage of the application increased..

[image: Performance comparison]

I want to lower the CPU usage and started the Performance Analysis in Visual Studio on both versions. After this, I compared both reports and it did show the following top 5 (Exclusive Samples):

[image: Performance comparison 2]

I have no idea what this DWrite.dll means and what its function is.. The only thing I saw from the Function Details was the following:

[image: Performance Function Details DWrite.dll]

I saw that igdumdim64.dll is being used by Intel, so I guess I cannot reduce this. Any help is highly appreciated. I really want to know how to reduce the CPU usage of those DLLs. Does anyone know how, or how I can found out to lower this?

Comment: I wanted to post this as a comment, but can't yet. I know that this is old and I can not help you, but I made an similar observation with my WPF app (rendering video like content to D3DImage at about 25fps). When my app runs on the primary monitor, it uses around 1% cpu.
When I drag it to the secondary monitor, the cpu goes up to about 7%.
Profiling showed most of the difference in igdumdim64.dll. Maybe your measurements were impacted by an unrelated effect like this.